# How to prevent memory allocation when using an LRUCache?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, allocation, android-lru-cache

I'm developing a game for the Android mobile platform, and everything is going great. However, I'm at a point where'd I'd like to address a few problems I've noticed whilst I've been developing and have ignored until now.

I'm using an LRUCache to store Android `Bitmap` objects with `Integer` keys. The problem is, when I attempt to store a `Bitmap` in the LRUCache with a key of primitive type `int`, the `Integer` object allocates memory with `Integer.valueOf(int)` to convert the primitive integer to the `Integer` object equivalent.

This is all well and good, but it causes concurrent garbage collection during the graphics rendering part of my main loop of my game, causing a drop in frame rate which creates a noticeable lag every so often when this garbage collection occurs. Below is a portion of my log which measures the time taken for graphics rendering to occur. My rendering method relies heavily on the use of loading `Bitmap` objects from the LRUCache, so it's understandable why it causes a delay like below when allocation is likely to be occurring quite frequently:

```
07-27 17:55:41.418: W/Render(13937): Time: 28ms
07-27 17:55:41.438: W/Render(13937): Time: 28ms
07-27 17:55:41.468: W/Render(13937): Time: 29ms
07-27 17:55:41.498: W/Render(13937): Time: 29ms
07-27 17:55:41.528: D/dalvikvm(13937): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 13% free 17265K/19756K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 17ms
07-27 17:55:41.548: W/Render(13937): Time: 44ms
07-27 17:55:41.578: W/Render(13937): Time: 27ms
07-27 17:55:41.608: W/Render(13937): Time: 28ms
07-27 17:55:41.628: W/Render(13937): Time: 28ms
07-27 17:55:41.658: W/Render(13937): Time: 29ms
```

Is there any way around `Integer.valueOf(int)` allocating memory in my application? Or is there an alternative to an LRUCache which accepts primitive types such as `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a Java cache that uses primitive `int` keys, but it shouldn't be too difficult to modify an open source cache (eg Guava): remove the "implements `Map`" statement, replace all `K`s with `int`s, and replace all `V`s with `Object`s (I don't have the source code in front of me, but every Java cache I've I've ever seen is just a `Map<K, V>` plus some logic for eviction). You will also need to replace the call to `key.hashCode()` with an inlined hash function (just search Google for an appropriate one, you can get an inexpensive one with `abs(key * prime_number) modulo size_of_backing_array`).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new open source primitive collections library called [Banana](https://github.com/omry/banana) which you can use.
There is an [LRU class](https://github.com/omry/banana/blob/master/banana/src/net/yadan/banana/utils/LRU.java) there which has primitive long keys.
Supported data is an int, a long or a Java Object - which is what you need.
Note that Banana is generally not thread safe so be sure to synchronize appropriately.

PS: The project is still at an early stage and I did not made my official release.
API may change in the future.

By the way, check out other classes like BlockAllocator, and the primitive linked lists and maps, I think they are particularly useful for Java game writers.